# WaitForMultipleObjects is not Waiting

Tags: c++, winapi, process, waitformultipleobjects

I have a function that is supposed to launch a group of processes by passing a command to CreateProcess. I am calling this function two times serially, but somehow the function exits and gets called the second time before the processes from the first group are finished.

> It seems to wait for only one of the processes to exit. The next batch
>   is launched when I close one of the applications from the first group
>   of processes.

I am using it to launch a group of applications together, and launch the next group when all of those processes exit. Why is my `WaitForMultipleObjects` call not waiting for all of the processes in the group to exit?

```
void ProcessLauncher::launch_processes(PROCESS_LIST_TYPE& processes)
{
unsigned long const CP_MAX_COMMANDLINE = 32768;
VECTOR_TYPE<PROCESS_INFORMATION> procs;
VECTOR_TYPE<HANDLE> pHandles;

for (auto proc : processes)
{
STRING_TYPE command = proc.program_name + L" " + proc.params;
STARTUPINFO sinfo = { 0 };
sinfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
try {
    CHAR_TYPE* commandline = new CHAR_TYPE[CP_MAX_COMMANDLINE];
    wcsncpy_s(commandline, CP_MAX_COMMANDLINE, command.c_str(), command.size() + 1);
    CreateProcess(nullptr,
        commandline,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        false,
        0,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        &sinfo,
        &pi);

    delete[]commandline;

    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    procs.push_back(pi);
    pHandles.push_back(pi.hProcess);
}
catch (std::bad_alloc&) {
    std::wcerr << L"Insufficient memory to launch application" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
}

if (WAIT_FAILED == WaitForMultipleObjects(pHandles.size(), pHandles.data(), TRUE, INFINITE))
    std::wcout << L"Failure waiting for process to terminate" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: How many processes are in the list in each invocation of your function?

Comment: @conio At the moment there are only two on each call.

Comment: @conio I forgot to mention some details about the wait. I added them in a blockquote to the question. The second batch is launched when I end one of the processes in the first group.

Comment: You aren't checking the process handles of your `CreateProcess` calls, and since you aren't properly quoting the application pathname for the command line, failure to create a process isn't just a theoretical possibility.

Answer (score 0):

As IInspectable lead me to find, the CreateProcess call was failing to create the process but I was still adding the handles to the vector. I changed it to only add the handles to the vector if CreateProcess returned an equivalent value to TRUE.